# How to play a YouTube video in a fragment in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, video-streaming

I am creating an app on `api29` and trying to implement different kinds of `fragments`. I have a :

- main activity (`MainActivity.java`)
- an activity to manage the fragment (`FragmentContent.java`)
- a layout `.xml` file (`activity_main.xml`)
- fragment `.xml` file (`fragment_video.xml`)

I have also downloaded `v1.2.2` of youtube API and placed the jar in the lib folder of my application and added internet access to the manifest file.

However, I am not sure on how to proceed and where to actually code

- the `MainActivity.java` or the `FragmentContent.java`

and what exactly to code

- a videoview or something altogether new

Comment: You mean your current process is like first call MainActivity and in activity you load Fragment right?

Comment: @Ali yes. main activity is the process on which fragments are then added

Comment: So *I am not sure on how to proceed and where to actually code* For youtube video playing write code in VIdeo fragment.

Answer (score 2):

- how to proceed and where to actually code

  > You want to code in `VideoFragment`
- what exactly to code:

  > Please follow this link: **[YouTube Android Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player)**
- a videoview or something altogether new

  > First add `jar` dependency `implementation files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')`

Now user below code in xml:

```
<com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
        android:id="@+id/youtube_player_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_200sdp"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header"
        />
```

Java code:

```
youtube_player_view = findViewById(R.id.youtube_player_view);

private void initVideo(final String videoId) {
        youtube_player_view.initialize(getResources().getString(R.string.youtube_api_key), new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean youtube_avalable) {
                //youTubePlayerMain = youTubePlayer;

                if (!youtube_avalable) {

                    youTubePlayerMain = youTubePlayer;

                    youTubePlayerMain.loadVideo(videoId);
                    youTubePlayerMain.setShowFullscreenButton(false);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
                if (youTubeInitializationResult.isUserRecoverableError()) {
                    youTubeInitializationResult.getErrorDialog(getApplicationContext(), 1).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), youTubeInitializationResult.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: how is the initVideo method invoked ? in the onCreateView function ?

Comment: Where you get videoId @fireball.1

Comment: @fireball.1 Is this my answer is useful for you?

Comment: I could not get the fragment running. Kept giving me a context error